# Run a function on every row of a pandas dataframe with dictionary return

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas

I have a number of functions that each return dictionary, which I would like to run on each row of a Pandas `DataFrame`.

For example

```
def calc_a(input):
    # do calculations
    return {"x": valuex, "y": valuey, "z": valuez}
```

I've obviously omitted all the calculation code since it's irrelevant. I think I might be able to purpose `pandas.DataFrame.apply`, but I'm not sure how to direct each key of the function's returned dictionary `x`, `y`, and `z` into separate columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you return a `Series` it should create separate columns for each key, this should be as simple as wrapping your existing dictionary in a `Series` call like:

```
return pd.Series({"x": valuex, "y": valuey, "z": valuez})
```